# Find the date and insert a new line under it without changing the value of the date in Notepad++

Tags: date, newline, notepad++

I have one column with data repeated in the following format

```
name
id
birthdate
..
.
.
```

and so on. I want Νotepad++ to find the date by using `([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+)` then insert a line after it without changing the actual date. But when I enter `([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+)\n` in replace window it replaces the actual date with `([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+)`. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

Find what: `(\d+-\d+-\d+)`
Replace with: `$1\n`